# Make imbeded cover text for stego program

Tags: c#, visual-studio, security, database-design, visual-c#-express-2010

I have stego program (in C#) and to add cover text it should be click on button to upload cover text to cover text box.. I tried to add option in Menu to create dropdown list that includes covers list so when click any one it will be uploaded to cover text box like image below.. Also can I make that cover text embedded with program???

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, no one answer that but I found simple solution its not very perfect but it solve this problem

in button just add this cod and put any text with any length between quotation

```
private void Options_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtCover.Text = "text ...........";
    }
```

Comment: the textCover is text box name